# Capturing header and continue matching - Regex

Tags: regex, m3u8

How to capture header `#EXTM3U` and continue matching `#EXTINF` pattern if the header exists.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:10.0,
media_w854021192_21533.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
media_w854021192_21534.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
media_w854021192_21535.ts
```

Regex:

```
(?<HEADER>#EXTM3U)\r?\n(?:#EXTINF:(?<DURATION>\-?\d+\.?\d+),(?<TITLE>.+)?\r?\n(?<URI>\S+))
```

[image]
[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fTTTWd/2)

Regex result should look like:

[image]

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/lPZSg4/1. Note that the consequent EXTINF blocks are matched as separate matches.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Man...Thank you!

Comment: Are you using it in PHP?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I am using PHP.

Comment: Does  https://ideone.com/N4xmv4 produce an expected result?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Can header be in separate match [0] and pattern "#EXTINF" in match [1], [2], [3]...? If not, the answer you provided is acceptable.

Comment: Please add expected result to the question.

Comment: Also, see https://ideone.com/Ema0Nn

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I added expected result.

Comment: Once you define a capturing group in the regex, you will get an item in the resulting array. You can't avoid `header` item in consequent matches.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Even though I achieved it using different regex, parsing was working even when I delete the header and that is what I don't want. It doesn't mater, I will use your first regex answer from "regex101". Please make a post.

Comment: Ok, I see, you actually may grab the necessary values via `$matches["URI"]`, etc. I posted a bit enhanced version of the regex.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Please see the regex https://regex101.com/r/ADaElK/1. The problem was capturing header and its properties in separate match while matching pattern #EXTINF. There was a problem when header is deleted (there should be no parsing at all) and when properties do not exist where the HLS becomes regular m3u playlist.

Comment: Sorry, I have got no clue what you need to do with that kind of a regex. I made [a verbose version](https://regex101.com/r/ADaElK/2). Do you mean you want to "combine" mine with that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
'~(?<HEADER>#EXTM3U|\G(?!\A))\R\K#EXTINF:(?<DURATION>-?\d+\.?\d+),(?<TITLE>.+)?\R(?<URI>\S+)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lPZSg4/3)

**Details**'

- `(?<HEADER>#EXTM3U|\G(?!\A))` - `HEADER` group matching either `#EXTM3U` or the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`)
- `\R` - a line break
- `\K` - a match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `#EXTINF:` - a substring
- `(?<DURATION>-?\d+\.?\d+)` - `DURATION` group matching an optional `-`, 1+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits
- `,` - a comma
- `(?<TITLE>.+)?` - an optional `TITLE` group matching 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\R` - a line break
- `(?<URI>\S+)` - an `URI` group matching 1 or more non-whitespace chars.